# How to add user input to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, nested, addition

I would like to show the edited code that still doesn't work, I tried to do as advised by first converting numbers into integers and then converting the list to a set. But it keeps throwing the same error from the console:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 3 5 6 7'

Here is the entire code:

```
lottery_numbers = [6, 7, 17, 5, 11, 25]
players = [
    {"name": "Connor", "numbers": {6, 7, 17, 34, 11, 25}},
    {"name": "Dave", "numbers": {3, 7, 35, 21, 5, 16}},
    {"name": "Emily", "numbers": {12, 28, 4, 16, 17, 5}},
    {"name": "Chris", "numbers": {34, 21, 3, 6, 13, 5}},
]
your_name = input("What is your name?")
given_numbers = input("Type any 6 numbers from 1 to 40: ")
your_numbers = [int(num) for num in given_numbers.split(',')]
your_combination = set(your_numbers)
players.append({"name": your_name, "numbers": your_combination})
print(your_combination)

numbers_matched = {}
prize_1 = 1000
prize_2 = 10000
prize_3 = 1000000

for player in players:

  numbers_matched = player["numbers"].intersection(lottery_numbers)
  print(f"{player['name']} has these numbers matched: {numbers_matched}")

  if len(numbers_matched) > 5:
    print(f"{player['name']} has won {prize_3} $")
  elif len(numbers_matched) > 4:
    print(f"{player['name']} has won {prize_2} $")
  elif len(numbers_matched) > 3:
    print(f"{player['name']} has won {prize_1} $")
  enter code here
```

Comment: the `"numbers"` key contains a set, not a dictionary, the `players` variable is a list. There is no nested dictionary here. `.update` does not exist on a list, you're looking for `.append`, `.split` returns a list, you need to turn that into a set using `set(given_numbers.split(','))`. That'll fix all of your code

Comment: ` numbers should be inside their own dictionary, too` , the numbers here are not in dictionary but in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). You can convert your `list` to `set` by doing `set(your_list)`, Note that set will omit duplicates from your list. Also if you want to enter 6 numbers separated by comma, `int(input("Type any 6 numbers from 1 to 40: "))` will throw an error, so it should be `input("Type any 6 numbers from 1 to 40: ")` and to convert to int do a list comprehension `your_numbers = [int(num) for num in given_numbers.split(',')]`

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the comments! I tried to change the code as advised but it keeps throwing the same error  
File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    your_numbers = [int(num) for num in given_numbers.split(',')]
  File "main.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    your_numbers = [int(num) for num in given_numbers.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 3 5 6 7'

your_numbers = [int(num) for num in given_numbers.split(',')]
your_combination = set(your_numbers)
players.append({"name": your_name, "numbers": your_combination})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is no nested dictionary here. `players` is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).  Specifically, a list of dictionaries. The `numbers` key in each of these dictionaries is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

So, to add another dictionary to the list, you use `.append`. Then to turn the list returned from `.split` into a set, you use a `set` cast.

Also, do not cast the comma separated number input to an `int`

```py
int(input("Type any 6 numbers from 1 to 40: "))
```

How do you expect python to turn `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` to an `int`? it wouldn't work. You can split this by `,` and cast each element to an `int`

We can do that using a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
[int(x.strip()) for x in given_numbers.split(',')]
```

(Note, I'm using [`.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to get rid of any extra whitespace)

Or just directly turn that into a `set`

```py
set(int(x.strip()) for x in given_numbers.split(','))
```

So this is how your full code could look-

```py
your_name = input("What is your name?")
given_numbers = input("Type any 6 numbers from 1 to 40: ")
your_numbers = set(int(x.strip()) for x in given_numbers.split(','))
players.append({"name": your_name, "numbers": your_numbers})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for explaining in such detail!  I am just doing an accelerated Python course from  0 and I do have some things messed up.. But neither your or other contributors solutions work, it keeps throwing the error - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '   Now if I don't try to convert to integer, I manage to add a set as you advised,  but the problem is that they are not integers so, then I can't compare them with lottery results.

Comment: @Dariana_Green what did you input to the second prompt

Comment: 2 3 4 7 6 7 25   - I add any 6 numbers, please see my updated post above, I pasted the entire code.. Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: @Dariana_Green they should be separated by commas..... If you want to separate them by space, change `.split(',')` to `.split(' ')`. Python cannot guess the separator magically, unfortunately.

Comment: WOW! Yes, it works now! Finally! just one comma and nothing worked. Thank you again for explaining about sets and converting to ing the list. In the course, only basic details about simple dictionaries are explained but I try to experiment myself to see how things work. Big thank you! ))))